# Science fiction book about some people who were mutants due to an environmental hazard

Tags: story-identification, books, morality

I read a story in the '80s (not sure when it was written) about some people who were mutants due to an environmental hazard. People ate black eggs from bubble-eyed goldfish to get high. I think the word 'freak' was in the title. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you think of any more details, however small, please edit them into your question. The more information you can provide, the better the chances that someone can ID this for you. And if anyone does correctly identify this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: [One of these stories](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=freak&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=SHORTFICTION&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=title_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=title_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=title_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=title_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title)?

Answer (score 5):

The mention of people eating goldfish eggs to get high immediately reminded me of *[Freaks' Amour](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?12747)*, a novel by Tom de Haven released in 1979, and more recently reworked as a graphic novel.

The novel deals with people coping with the aftereffects of the "Blofeld blast", an accidental radiation leak which caused massive mutations. A review [here](https://www.flayrah.com/4871/book-review-freaks-amour-tom-de-haven) describes the story:

> The main character, named Grinner, is a fish-man. He has a bit of a
> drug habit... the substance that gets him high is ordinary salt
> (that's how a classy writer puts meaning into the way his character
> "takes things with a grain of salt.") Grinner makes a living as an
> actor in a brutal kind of theater – erotic performance with other
> freaks and animal-people, for privileged "normal people" seeking a
> freak show. He wears the mask of a "normal person" on stage, but
> behind it his face is distorted into a permanent smile. As a
> mask-behind-the-mask, it puts a touch of irony on the absurdity and
> tragedy he experiences from the paradoxes of a fragmented world.

One of the effects of the radiation is on "pet goldfish that quadrupled in length and mass and started to anally extrude tiny, green-dappled hard-shell eggs ...". The main character's brother, Flour, cultivates these goldfish to sell their eggs as "DeathEggs, the ultimate narcotic".

The book is freely available form the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/freaksamour0000deha).